# ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class ScikitLearn Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a problem with this code. The error is on the line: ppn.fit(X_train, y_train)
I just use Python 3.7

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False)


X = df.iloc[:, 1:44].values
y = df.iloc[:, 48].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

X_train = np.isnan(X_train)
y_train = np.isnan(y_train)
X_test = np.isnan(X_test)


ppn = Perceptron(max_iter=40, tol=0.001, eta0=0.1, random_state=0)
ppn.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = ppn.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.isnan(y_pred)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: And if you check your data - does it indeed have only a single class/category in column 48?

Comment: Yes, column 48 has only one category

Comment: And for GaussianProcessClassifier() is the same?

Comment: But for DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=5) the same code works